# SyntaxError: Unexpected token u, not parsing

Tags: ajax, node.js

I'm trying to send a post request like so:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url:"/game/register",
   data: {"user": username},
   success: function(){console.log("SUCCESS");},
   dataType: 'json'
});
```

and I'm receiving it on there server like so:

```
var jsonString = '';
req.setEncoding('utf8');

req.on('data', function (data) {
   jsonString += data;
});

req.on('end', function () {
   console.log(jsonString);
   reqData = JSON.parse(jsonString);
   //console.log(reqData);
   respond(200, JSON.stringify(reqData));
});
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to parse.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
```

It seems to build the string fine because I can print it, just not convert it to JSON. Any ideas?

Comment: What's printed?

Comment: the string printed is: "user=WhateverUsernameIs"

Answer (score 0):

From the error I'd say that `JSON.parse` is getting something that's not JSON syntax. Maybe `'undefined'` ? Add console message around this line,

```
jsonString += data
```

check for the type of data. Is it a string?

Edit: Based on your reply in comment, your data are not JSON, so no wonder that `JSON.parse()` fails. [JSON syntax](http://json.org/) looks like this:

```
{"user":"WhateverUsernameIs"}
```

Comment: I just put a few messages around it, data is indeed a string like such: "user=WhateverUsernameIs" .

Comment: Well, that's not JSON. That's the error you're looking for.